# How do I use a list from one site on another SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, error

I have used SP Designer to create List web parts that can be used across sites in the same collection. The web parts I created a few months ago work fine.

But now when I try to create a new web part using SP designer I get the error message " The file you imported is not valid. Verify that the file is a Web Part description file (*.webpart or *.dwp) and that it contains well-formed XML." when I try to place the newly created Web part on a page.

Odd that the web parts I created months ago using the same method still work fine. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is may due to the deprecation and removal of the DataFormWebPart as part of MC242207.

Similar issue for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/315516/xml-code-no-longer-working-in-sharepoint.html